# How to change query result into another value in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

For example, I have a column named 'form_type' consisted of int (1-4)

```
id_event|form_type
--------|----------
001     |1
001     |3
001     |4
002     |2
002     |1
```

When i query

> SELECT `form_type` FROM `some_table` WHERE `id_event` = 001

I would get 1,3 and 4 of course. But is it possible to change those values to something else on the database layer? For example, I would get strings instead of int like so, 1 = 'Name', 3 = 'Email', 4 = 'City' etc. If it's possible, what would be the query? Or is the only way to do that would be on the application side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN form_type = 1 THEN 'Name'
        WHEN form_type = 3 THEN 'Email'
        WHEN form_type = 4 THEN 'City'
        ELSE 'some default value'
    END
FROM some_table
WHERE id_event = 001
```

Using `CASE` you define what you want returned for the value in your table. 
`CASE` example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ELT(form_type, 'Name', 'Unknown', 'Email', 'City')
FROM some_table
WHERE id_event = 001
```

[ELT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt)

But I'd recommend to create a table which stores the relation between the number and the string, and join it into the query for to *get strings instead of int*.

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach would be to have a reference table in the database with this information.  Then you would use `JOIN`:

```
create table forms (
    form_type int primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);

insert into forms (form_type, name)
    values (1, 'Name'),
           (2, ???),  -- unclear what goes here
           (3, 'Email'), 
           (4,  'City');
```

Then use `JOIN` to get the name:

```
select t.*, f.name
from t join
     forms f
     using (form_type);
```

Why do you want to store this information in the database?  Simple:  CONSISTENCY!

If you start using `CASE` expressions in your queries, you are proliferating the problem.  This is risky:

- Different case expressions might use different strings (say, "E-mail" versus "email").
- If you add new forms, you have to change a lot of code.
- If you decide to change the name of something then you have to change a lot of code.

*You want the data stored in tables.*  You do not want this implemented as business rules in the code, because that is brittle and error-prone.

I should note that MySQL does offer two alternatives to an explicit reference table.  If `form_type` is only used in one table, then an `enum` is a convenient alternative.  Or, you can use a generated column in the table to generate the string.